# Show that $S'$ is closed for any $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I show that $S'$ is closed for any $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$? Here $S'$ denotes the set of all limit points of $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

If I let $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Then $S'$ is closed if and only if its complement $\mathbb{C}\backslash S'$ is open. $\mathbb{C}\backslash S'$ is open if and only if for $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash S'$ there is $\varepsilon  > 0$ such that $D\left( {z,\varepsilon } \right) \subseteq \mathbb{C}\backslash S'$. Here $D\left( {z,\varepsilon } \right)$ denotes an open disc centred at $z$ , with radius $\varepsilon > 0$.

Now I want to show $\mathbb{C}\backslash S'$ is open, so I let $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash S'$. This means $z \notin S'$. Therefore $z$ is not a limit point of $S$. Here is where I'm stuck , because this means $D\left( {z,\varepsilon } \right) \cap S = \emptyset$, but this does not mean $D\left( {z,\varepsilon } \right) \subseteq \mathbb{C}\backslash S'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue from where you left:
**Claim.** $D(z, \epsilon) \cap S' = \emptyset.$
*Proof.* Suppose not. Let $z' \in D(z, \epsilon) \cap S'.$
Choose $r > 0$ sufficiently small such that $D(z', r) \subset D(z, \epsilon)$.
(You can do this since $D(z, \epsilon)$ is open.)

Now, since $z'$ is a limit point (it's an element of $S'$), we must have that $D(z', r) \cap S \neq \emptyset$.
As $D(z', r) \subset D(z, \epsilon)$, this gives us that $D(z, \epsilon) \cap S \neq \emptyset$. A contradiction!

---

Thus, you get that $D(z, \epsilon) \subseteq \Bbb C\setminus S'$, as desired.